# MULE ANYPOINT STUDIO stops working

Tags: xml, mule, anypoint-studio

I install update for anypoint studio if I  install object reference or git or some other plugin or extension of anypoint studio studio stops working correctly, In pallete can see anything and I cant load conf.xml,.... chcek the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIakv.png)

Comment: Can you provide further details regarding the versions of Anypoint Studio you are using and of the plugins that you installed?

Comment: If you could post your log files for AnyPoint Studio, that would help evaluate what issues are at play.

Comment: [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Answer (score 0):

As per the picture I can see that you have imported your project successfully. I think there won't be any issue after you added your `plugin`. I think you refresh your project and build once. If you won't see after this.

You can try these steps:

1. from your anypoint studio - window>show view>others>search mule
   palette
2. restart your anypoint